# How to approach proving $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(\int^{b}_{a}(f(x))^ndx)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\max\{f(x):x\in[a,b]\}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be positive and continuous. Let $M = \max\{f(x):x \in [a,b]\}.$
Could anyone advise me on how to establish the following result:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(\int^{b}_{a}(f(x))^ndx)^{\frac{1}{n}}=M.$$

Fix $n \in \mathbb{N}.$ By Mean Value theorem, $(\int^{b}_{a}(f(x))^ndx)^{\frac{1}{n}}=f(c)(b-a)^{\frac{1}{n}},$ for some $c \in [a,b]?$

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\sum a_i^n\right)^{1/n}=\max(a_i)$, since $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\max(a_i)^n}{a_j^n}=\infty$ if $a_j\neq\max(a_i)$.  Therefore we have

$$\begin{align} \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\int_{a}^b f(x)^n\mathrm dx\right)^{1/n}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{i=ak}^{bk} f\left(\frac{i}{k}\right)^n\cdot k^{-1}\right)^{1/n}\\
&=\lim_{k\to\infty} \max\left(\left\{f\left(\frac{i}{k}\right)\mid ak\leq i\leq bk\right\}\right) \\
&=\max(\{f(x)\mid a\leq x\leq b\})\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you. Could you elaborate why  $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\sum a_i^n\right)^{1/n}=\max(a_i)?$ Isn't $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\max(a_i)^n}{a_j^n}=\infty$ if $a_j\neq\max(a_i)?$

Comment: Oh, yeah, let me fix that.  The same idea, though: all other $a_j$ are negligible in comparison to the maximum value as $n$ grows large (ex: $(2^n+3^n)^{1/n}\to 3$ for large $n$).